# problem in upper and lower items sum and product formula

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$\hat{\alpha_1}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\cos(y_i-\beta_i\hat{X_i})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i}$$


$$\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \left[\dfrac{1}{I_0(\lambda\rho)}\right]^n \exp \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda \rho \cos(x_i -X_i)\dfrac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(c-\eta_1 \cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i))}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Rita, please, complete your code with all the necessary code between  the `\documentclass` and the `\end{document}`. I compiled your equations here and I could see no "problem". So please, complete the code and clarify what you mean by "problem".

Comment: Make your example start with `\documentclass` end with `\end{document}` and not use `$$`

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Dear @Rita ana, so far you should learn something from received comments and answers. (i) tell us, why you newer  provides small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass[<opions, if any>]{<used document class>}` followed by loading packages, which are relevant to your problem, than `begin{document}` ... code of your problem ... `\end{document}` as you can see in all received answers, which demonstrate your problem; (ii) why not consider given advises to change used syntax in typing of math expression; (iii) why so far you not accept any of received answers. are they all worth less?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\limits` for placing indices right under and above the sum and the product sign. (If it was your question)

Instead of `$$...$$` you should use `\[...\]`, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Also, I changed `\hat{\alpha_1}` to `\hat{\alpha}_1`, then the `hat` will be placed only above `\alpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\hat{\alpha}_1=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}w_i\cos(y_i-\beta_i\hat{X}_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}w_i}\]

\[\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \left[\dfrac{1}{I_0(\lambda\rho)}\right]^n \exp \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda \rho \cos(x_i -X_i)\dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(c-\eta_1 \cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\eta_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i))}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There should never be consecutive displays, even less if separated by a blank line.

Comment: @egreg What is the cause for that? And what can I do instead of it?

Comment: In this case probably `align*`, with alignment point after the arrow, should solve the issue.